# my php code can't get the value in the url

Tags: php, mysql

I designed a webpage.In this webpage i read the data and put them into a dropdownlist as you can see here:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
                <?php
                    include("../inc/mysql.php");
                        $q2="SELECT * FROM tbl_group;";
                        $r2=mysql_query($q2);
                        $n2=mysql_num_rows($r2);
                            for($i=0;$i<$n2;$i++){
 $m2=mysql_fetch_array($r2);
?>

       <tr>
   <td><a href="insertpage.php?id=<?php echo $m2['id']?>">نمایش</a></td>
       </tr>
    php }?> 
         </table>
```

I link every rows that i read ,and in another query .So after click on each rows my **id** is sent to the url ,because i need the **id** value to select a subgroup in another query .In below you can see that i am using id value to select a query :

```
                <table width="200" border="1">
                <?php
                    include("../inc/mysql.php");
                    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                        $q23="SELECT * FROM tbl_cat where idgroup=".$_GET['id'].";";
                        $r23=mysql_query($q23);
                        $n23=mysql_num_rows($r23);
                            for($i=0;$i<$n23;$i++){
                                $m23=mysql_fetch_array($r23);
                ?>

<tr>
       <td><a href="insertpage.php?catid=<?php echo $m23['id'];?>">انتخاب</a></td>
        <td><?php echo $m23['cat']?></td>
   </tr>
  <?php }}?>
  </table>
```

So in this query i send the **catid** to url to insert in my table but my code can't detect the **catid** variable in my url ;

I need this value to insert in my table.

all of these code is placed in a **phpfile**

```
  <?php

     if(isset($_GET["catid"])){
   $cat=$_GET['catid'];
   include("../inc/mysql.php");
   $q="INSERT INTO tbl_text (idcat) VALUES ('$cat');";
   $r=mysql_query($q);

   }

?>
```

So my problem is in the second query my code can't read the **catid** that i sent before via first query ?

thank you

Comment: `$q23="SELECT * FROM tbl_cat where idgroup=".$_GET['id'].";";` are you sure the `";"` is alright?

Comment: You should be thankful it didn't work. Because, if it had. You could be using an application full of MySQL injections

Comment: you miss a semicolumn here :
<td><a href="insertpage.php?id=<?php echo $m2['id']; ?>">نمایش</a></td>

Comment: Fallen i check it without ";"

Comment: the catid is added to url ,but in the insert query the php can't detect the value in url

Comment: `$r2=mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_error());` change it and display DB errors and check db for fix errors!!!

Comment: mr eskandari my insert query doesn't work because the catid isn't seted :if(isset($_GET["catid"]))

Comment: aghaye eskandari ?just persian gulf..

Comment: See related questions on [using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1) and [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: miken32:so you mean because of injection php doesn't allow to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you did a mistake

```
 $q2="SELECT * FROM tbl_group;";
                             -
```

replace it by

```
  $q2="SELECT * FROM tbl_group";
```

Comment: this part of code doesn't have any problem ,but my problem is here : <?php

     if(isset($_GET["catid"])){
   $cat=$_GET['catid'];
   include("../inc/mysql.php");
   $q="INSERT INTO tbl_text (idcat) VALUES ('$cat');";
   $r=mysql_query($q);

   }

?>.i cant read the catid

Comment: in SQL `;` is a terminal statement or considered as End of line.. So does it change meaning after removing `;`??

Comment: Semicolons passed in the query are just ignored. They will not cause code to fail.